# Archer GRC: Calculate current date when values list changes

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I need assistance with a calculation that will set a date field (Respondent Status Date Change) to the current date each time values list (Respondent Status) has a change in value:

[image: Status values list and Date field]

```
IF(
VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Pending Assignment"),VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Work in Progress"),VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Escalated to ERD"),VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Questions to Risk Group"),VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Optimization Opportunity"),VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Completed"),VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"No Selection")))
NOW(),
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer as accepted if any of the answers help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use DDEs to implement what you want. You will not have to wait for a save or an apply.

So basically,

**RULE**:

Respondent Status

"CHANGED TO"

Pending Assignment
OR
Work in Progress
OR
Escalated to ERD
OR
Questions to Risk Group
OR
Optimization Opportunity
OR
Completed
OR
No Selection

**ACTION**:

Set [Respondent Status Date Change] to Current Date

**But if a calculation is absolutely essential:**

Create a copy of the field 'Respondent Status' say 'Previous Respondent Status'. 'Previous Respondent Status' field will be calculated and the formula for this field will be:

[Respondent Status]

Now, in the calculation order, place this field below the 'Respondent Status Date Change' field.

The calculation in the 'Respondent Status Date Change' would be:

```
 IF([Respondent Status]<>[Previous Respondent Status], NOW(),
    IF([Respondent Status]=[Previous Respondent Status], [Respondent Status Date Change]))
```